# SQL function return-type: TABLE vs SETOF records

Tags: sql, postgresql, return-type, sql-function, sql-types

What's the difference between a function that returns `TABLE` vs `SETOF records`, all else equal.

```
CREATE FUNCTION events_by_type_1(text) RETURNS TABLE(id bigint, name text) AS $$
    SELECT id, name FROM events WHERE type = $1;
$$ LANGUAGE SQL STABLE;

CREATE FUNCTION events_by_type_2(text) RETURNS SETOF record AS $$
    SELECT id, name FROM events WHERE type = $1;
$$ LANGUAGE SQL STABLE;
```

These functions seem to return the same results. See this [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/5f36a/1).

Answer (score 32, accepted):

When returning `SETOF record` the output columns are not typed and not named. Thus this form can't be used directly in a FROM clause as if it was a subquery or a table.

That is, when issuing:

```
SELECT * from events_by_type_2('social');
```

we get this error:

> ERROR:  a column definition list is required for functions returning
>   "record"

It can be "casted" into the correct column types by the SQL caller though. This form does work:

```
SELECT * from events_by_type_2('social') as (id bigint, name text);
```

and results in:

```
 id |      name      
----+----------------
  1 | Dance Party
  2 | Happy Hour
 ...
```

For this reason `SETOF record` is considered less practical. It should be used only when the column types of the results are not known in advance.

Comment: @MattDiPasquale: I'm not aware of any performance difference. However in both cases if using these functions in more complex queries, you might be interested in [How to avoid multiple function evals with the (func()).* syntax in an SQL query?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18369778)

Answer (score 18):

This answer is only to remember alternative **context where *TABLE* and *SETOF* are equivalent**.

As @a_horse_with_no_name pointed,   it is not a *RETURNS SETOF "unknown record"*, is a defined one.

---

In this example, the types `table` and `setof` are equivalent,

```
CREATE TYPE footype AS (score int, term text);

CREATE FUNCTION foo() RETURNS SETOF footype AS $$
   SELECT * FROM ( VALUES (1,'hello!'), (2,'Bye') ) t;
$$ language SQL immutable;

CREATE FUNCTION foo_tab() RETURNS TABLE (score int, term text) AS $$
   SELECT * FROM ( VALUES (1,'hello!'), (2,'Bye') ) t;
$$ language SQL immutable;

SELECT * FROM foo();      -- works fine!
SELECT * FROM foo_tab();  -- works fine and is equivalent.
```

The *RETURNS SETOF* have the **advantage of reuse type** (see *footype*), that is impossible with *RETURNS TABLE*.

Comment: `returns setof footype` is something different then `RETURNS SETOF record` because now it's no longer an "unknown" type. The columns of `footype` are well defined.

Comment: Thank you, @PeterKrauss. :-)