# Why RETURN NEXT cannot have a parameter in function with OUT parameters?

Tags: postgresql

I can write next:

```
create type my_fn as( id int, name text);

create function my_fn()
returns setof my_fn
language plpgsql as $$ 
DECLARE
  _res record;
BEGIN
select 1, 'text' into _res;
return next _res;
END $$
```

But why I write, I suppose, same thing:

```
create function my_fn()
returns TABLE ( id int, name text)
language plpgsql as $$ 
DECLARE
  _res record;
BEGIN
select 1, 'text' into _res;
return next _res;
END $$
```

I get the error:

```
ERROR: RETURN NEXT cannot have a parameter in function with OUT parameters
```

It seems `PostgreSQL` can use explicit parameter to return. And if not provided it can use OUT parameters, can not?

Answer (score 1):

The two function definitions are not the same:

The first one returns a single column (of a composite type), while the second function returns two columns.

But the error message is about something different:

If you define a set returning function as

```
RETURNS SETOF atype
```

then you have to return values like this:

```
RETURN NEXT <expression of type atype>;
```

If you define the function as

```
RETURNS TABLE (a atype, b btype)
```

then you have to do it like this:

```
a := <expression>;
b := <expression>;
RETURN NEXT;
```

Comment: Yes, I did that. but the question is about `why` I can not use `RETURN NEXT <expression of type TABLE>;`

Comment: And according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35991076/4632019) answer: `SETOF and TABLE are equivalent`

Comment: To answer the question "why", you'd have to dig through PostgreSQL commit logs and mailing list archives.