# pgstattuple query performance

Tags: performance, postgresql, statistics, query-performance

I am trying to build query that checks dead tuples, live tuples percent, free space etc. in all my users tables using pgstattuple extension. So, I came up with this query:

```
SELECT schemaname, 
relname, 
(pgstattuple(schemaname ||'.'||relname)).*
FROM pg_statio_user_tables;
```

pg_statio_user_tables is a pg_catalog view, that uses another system view. So at first glance the query looks quite simple, but it ended up with a total execution time of 27 minutes for 882 objects in db.

The execution plan for this query:
[image: execution plan]

Is there a way to rewrite query still using pgstattuple so it'll perform decent?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It gets a lot faster if you run the function in a subquery and only decompose the resulting row type on the next level:

```
SELECT s.schemaname, s.relname, st.*
FROM pg_statio_user_tables s
    ,pgstattuple(s.schemaname ||'.'|| s.relname) AS st;
```

(That's an implicit `LATERAL JOIN`. In versions befor Postgres 9.3 use a subquery instead.)

This way, the function is only called once per row in `pg_statio_user_tables`. Unfortunately you are stumbling over a weak spot in the Postgres query planner (parser). Craig explains in more details in this related answer:

- [How to avoid multiple function evals with the (func()).* syntax in an SQL query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18369778/how-to-avoid-multiple-function-evals-with-the-func-syntax-in-an-sql-query/18370271#18370271)

And if all you need from the `pg_statio_user_tables` view are table and schema name, you can have that *much faster, yet*:

```
SELECT c.oid::regclass::text AS tbl, (st).*
FROM   pg_class c
JOIN   pg_namespace n ON n.oid = c.relnamespace
      ,pgstattuple(c.oid::regclass::text) st
WHERE  c.relkind = 'r'            -- only tables
AND    n.nspname NOT LIKE 'pg_%'  -- exclude system schemas
ORDER  BY 1;
```

Comment: How much faster did it get for you?

Comment: my query needed 561486.985 ms (~9,4min), yours with lateral join: 155152.465 ms (2,6min), with pg_class 169894.413 ms (2,8min). Still far from speedy Gonzales, but much better :)