# Pass array variable as parameter to another function

Tags: arrays, postgresql, parameter-passing, plpgsql, stored-functions

I initialized two arrays in a function, one for numbers (list of amounts) and the other for text (list of invoices). I want to call another function from this one and pass these two arrays as parameters.
I can call the function this way and everything is OK:

```
select function_2('{110011-0115-7}'::text[], '{100}'::numeric[])
```

But when I want send a variable that holds a text array the array seems to be empty:

```
select function_2(ARRAY[invoice_list], ARRAY[amount_list]);
```

Function definition:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION function_1(OUT out_code1 integer
                                    , OUT out_message1 text)
  RETURNS RECORD AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
   counter      numeric;
   inv_cur      record;
   invoice_list text[];
   amount_list  numeric[]; 
BEGIN
   FOR inv_cur IN
      SELECT "ID", "AMOUNT"
      FROM "INVOICE"
      WHERE "ACCOUNT_ID" = in_account
   LOOP
       --Adding invoices to invoice array
        invoice_list[counter] := inv_cur."ID";

        --Adding amounts to amount array
        amount_list[counter] := inv_cur."AMOUNT";

        --Increasing counter for array indexes
        counter := counter + 1;
   END LOOP;

   --Caling other function
   SELECT * FROM function_2(ARRAY[invoice_list], ARRAY[amount_list]);
END
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
```

Other function definition:

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION function_2(in_invoices text[]
                                     , in_amounts numeric[]) ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could fix your function like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION function_1(in_account int
                                , OUT out_code1 int
                                , OUT out_message1 text)
  RETURNS RECORD AS
$func$
DECLARE
   counter    int := 1;  -- use int and initialize
   inv_cur      record;
   invoice_list text[];
   amount_list  numeric[]; 
BEGIN

   FOR inv_cur IN
      SELECT "ID", "AMOUNT"
      FROM   "INVOICE"
      WHERE  "ACCOUNT_ID" = in_account  -- !!!
      ORDER  BY "ID" -- don't you care about sort order?
   LOOP
       --Adding invoices to invoice array
        invoice_list[counter] := inv_cur."ID";

        --Adding amounts to amount array
        amount_list[counter] := inv_cur."AMOUNT";

        --Increasing counter for array indexes
        counter := counter + 1;
   END LOOP;

   --  Calling other function
   SELECT f.outfield_1, f.outfield_2  -- replace with actual names!
   INTO  out_code1, out_message1
   FROM  function_2(invoice_list, amount_list) f;

END
$func$  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
```

#### Notes

- The function variable counter must be initialized or it's set to NULL.
- `in_account` is interpreted as column name of table `"INVOICE"` (which it probably isn't). Seems a function parameter is missing.
- Replace my added `ORDER  BY "ID"` with your actual desired sort order.
- You *need* to assign the result of your final `SELECT`.
- `invoice_list` and `amount_list` are arrays already. Only wrap them into another ARRAY layer if you want to add another array dimension (I doubt that.)

Now the function should *work*. It's still **expensive nonsense** ...

Array handling the way you do it is very expensive. Looping is expensive, too. Replace `function_1()` with this query:

```
SELECT f.*
FROM  (
   SELECT function_2(array_agg("ID"), array_agg("AMOUNT")) AS f
   FROM  (
      SELECT "ID", "AMOUNT"
      FROM   "INVOICE"
      WHERE  "ACCOUNT_ID" = in_account  -- your input here!
      ORDER  BY "ID"
      ) t1
   ) t2;
```

You could make do with a single query level:

```
SELECT (function_2(array_agg("ID" ORDER BY "ID")
                 , array_agg("AMOUNT" ORDER BY "ID"))).*
FROM   "INVOICE"
WHERE  "ACCOUNT_ID" = in_account;
```

But performance would be much worse. The version with subqueries has to sort only once and also calls the function only once:

- [How to avoid multiple function evals with the (func()).* syntax in an SQL query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18369778/how-to-avoid-multiple-function-evals-with-the-func-syntax-in-an-sql-query/18370271#18370271)

You can wrap that into an SQL function if need be.