# postgres select returning no records when a function does not return anything

Tags: postgresql

I am having a hard time wording this question--

i have this simple select statement that returns a record

```
SELECT q.qid,q.question,depth,active  
FROM q 
JOIN qp ON q.qid = qp.descendant where qid=723
order by depth
```

this correctly returns the 1 record it is after

however when i include a function in the select statement it no longer returns the records and I am not sure why that is.

```
SELECT q.qid,q.question,depth,active,(getprevquestiontemp(qid)).qid parent  
FROM q 
JOIN qp ON q.qid = qp.descendant where qid=723
order by depth
```

this is the function

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION getprevquestiontemp(cur_qid integer)
  RETURNS SETOF q AS
$BODY$ 
SELECT q.* FROM q 
JOIN qp ON q.qid = qp.ancestor WHERE qp.descendant = cur_qid
AND depth = 1;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE sql VOLATILE
  COST 100
  ROWS 1000;
```

Comment: What does the function `getprevquestiontemp` do? Is that a set returning function? If yes use it in the FROM clause with an outer join

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name just added the function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use the function in the SELECT list, use it like a table with an outer join:

```
SELECT q.qid, q.question, depth, active, g.qid parent  
FROM q 
  JOIN qp ON q.qid = qp.descendant 
  LEFT JOIN getprevquestiontemp(qid) as g(qid) ON true
where qid=723
order by depth
```

---

Unrelated, but: if you declare the function as `stable` the optimizer could [inline]https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Inlining_of_SQL_functions() the function which might lead to better performance

Comment: can you give a little more explanation on why the query needs to be done this way?

Comment: this helped me understand it better https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18369778/how-to-avoid-multiple-function-evals-with-the-func-syntax-in-an-sql-query/18370271#18370271